# Order By Dynamically, multiple fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following statements in one of my SQL queries:

```
      CASE WHEN @Ordering = 'asc' THEN YEAR(TimeIn) ASC, DATEPART(WEEK, TimeIn) ASC END,
      CASE WHEN @Ordering = 'desc' then YEAR(TimeIn) DESC, DATEPART(WEEK, TimeIn) DESC END
```

but I'm getting an error:

Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure Line 43 [Batch Start Line 4]
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ASC'.

I've tried searching for examples, but they all relate to one field, and not multiple as I'm trying to do there.

Can anyone advise how I can correct the above please?

Comment: The problem is the `ASC/DESC`, they'll have to be moved outside the `CASE` expression. So the only way doing this will be dynamic SQL I think.

Comment: Ahh ok, that sucks. Really wanted to avoid dynamic SQL :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can repeat the same `CASE`, the direction comes after the `END` of the `CASE`:

```
ORDER BY  CASE WHEN @Ordering = 'asc'  THEN YEAR(TimeIn)           END ASC, 
          CASE WHEN @Ordering = 'asc'  THEN DATEPART(WEEK, TimeIn) END ASC,
          CASE WHEN @Ordering = 'desc' THEN YEAR(TimeIn)           END DESC, 
          CASE WHEN @Ordering = 'desc' THEN DATEPART(WEEK, TimeIn) END DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

how about this

```
order by 
 (CASE @Ordering when 'asc' then 1 when 'desc' then -1 else 0 end)*TimeIn ASC,
 (CASE @Ordering when 'asc' then 1 when 'desc' then -1 else 0 end)*DATEPART(WEEK, TimeIn) ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

We can perform the same thing in little short way, please try it:

```
ORDER BY  
CASE WHEN @Ordering = 'asc'  THEN 
    CONCAT(YEAR(TimeIn),DATEPART(WEEK, TimeIn)) 
END ASC, 
CASE WHEN @Ordering = 'desc' THEN 
    CONCAT(YEAR(TimeIn),DATEPART(WEEK, TimeIn)) 
END DESC
```

Note: CONCAT can be used in SQL Server >= 2012, in lower version we can use + instead for concatenation.